# Pattern Matching Alphabetical String- Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, alphabetical

My regex expression in python as follows:

```
r'(?s)(\\thinhline\n\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([^\W\d])(.*?)(\n *\\\\)'
```

My test string:

```
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
Jacobi
  & $\JacobiP{\alpha}{\beta}{n}@{x}$
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(1 - x)^{\alpha} (1 + x)^{\beta}$
  & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, &\text{$n = 0$} \end{cases}$
    $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, & \text{$n = 0$}\end{cases}$
  & $\dfrac{\pochhammer{n+\alpha+\beta+1}{n}}{2^n n!}$
  & $\dfrac{n (\alpha-\beta)}{2n+\alpha+\beta}$
  & $\alpha,\beta > -1$
\\
```

Match captures:

```
Match 1
1.  \thinhline \\[-16pt]
2.  J
3.  acobi & $\JacobiP{\alpha}{\beta}{n}@{x}$ & $(-1,1)$ & $(1 - x)^{\alpha} (1 + x)^{\beta}$ & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, &\text{$n = 0$} \end{cases}$ $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, & \text{$n = 0$}\end{cases}$ & $\dfrac{\pochhammer{n+\alpha+\beta+1}{n}}{2^n n!}$ & $\dfrac{n (\alpha-\beta)}{2n+\alpha+\beta}$ & $\alpha,\beta > -1$
4.  \\
```

Why is group 2 only getting the first character of "J"? How do I get group 2 to get the entirety of the word "Jacobi"?

Comment: You might want to use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) instead.

Comment: I am? I have to use this pattern on other strings as well so I can't directly match the word "Jacobi",

Comment: I m not saying you **must** use it, but it would probably make your reg ex more readable. Also, make sure you understand what's the difference (check examples at "7.2.5.8. Raw String Notation" in the link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [**quantifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) with your character class.

```
([^\W\d]+)
        ^
        |________ means match the preceding "one or more" times.
```

But while this may fix the issue, I would use the following to match only letter characters.

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**Note:** Your original character class matches letter characters and the underscore, so if you need to match the underscore character as well you can simply add it to the class.

Comment: Thanks, it works well but how could this include spaces?

Comment: To also allow spaces add it as well. `[a-zA-Z ]+`